# Regex match quotes inside bracket regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regex that must match only the text inside quotes but not in a comment, my macthes must only the strings in bold

> <**"love"**;>
>
> >/*"love"*/<
>
> <>**'love'**<>
>
> **"lo**
>
> **more love**
>
> **ve"**

I'm stunck on this:

```
/(?:((\"|\')(.|\n)*?(\"|\')))(?=(?:\/\**\*\/))/gm
```

The first one `(?:((\"|\')(.|\n)*?(\"|\')))` match all the strings
the second one `(?=(?:\/\**\*\/))` doesn't match text inside quotes inside `/* "mystring" */`

bit my logic is cleary wrong

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me an i.e. please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to avoid commented parts is to match them before. The global pattern looks like this:

```
/(capture parts to avoid)|target/
```

Then use a callback function for the replacement (when the capture group exists, return the match without change, otherwise, replace the match with what you want.

Example:

```
var result = text.replace(/(\/\*[^*]*(?:\*+(?!\/)[^*]*)*\*\/)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*'/g,
    function (m, g1) {
        if (g1) return g1;
        return '<b>' + m + '</b>';
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the regex is perfect and I understood more on the regex logic. Thank a lot again

Comment: @Morticella: there is no problem with single quotes, refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just need to use a negative lookahead to check for the comment end `*/`?

But first, I'd split the string into separate lines

```
 var arrayOfLines = input_str.split(/\r?\n/);
```

or, without empty lines:

```
 var arrayOfLines = input_str.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

and then use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/tB9oL5/5):

`["']([^'"]+)["'](?!.*\*\/)`

Sample code:

```
var rebuilt_string = ''
var re = /["']([^'"]+)["'](?!.*\*\/)/g; 
var subst = '<b>$1</b>'; 

for (i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++)
{
   rebuilt_string = rebuilt_string + arrayOfLines[i].replace(re, subst) + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: `("|')([^"']+)("|')(?!\*\/(.|\n)*\*\/)` I changed a bit the regex but it's still match the string inside the comment

Comment: I'd rather split the multiline input first, and then apply the `["']([^'"]+)["'](?!.*\*\/)` regex. However, you've got an answer from C&H that works for you.